# how to transfer xml created in angular to a file in node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, xml, bpmn

i wanna use it every time from  my bpmn project in angular post xml created in a Separate file inside my backend .For this I created a directory in backend.The following codes is in node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    let body = '';
    let dir = './example-dir';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
    });
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    req.on('end', function() {
      fs.writeFile(dir + '/result.xml', body, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send('You just created new xml file!')
      });
    });
  })

  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  app.set('port', port);
  var server = http.createServer(app)

   server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Connected to port ' + port )
  })
```

i created a restapi.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestapiService {
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    })
  }  

  savexml(item):Observable<{}>{
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL,item, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1)

    )

  }
```

The following codes is in app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'MyAngularBPMNTest';

  modeler;
  form: any[];
  constructor(private http: RestapiService , private Http :HttpClient ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.modeler = new Modeler({
      container: '#canvas',
      width: '100%',
      height: '600px',
      additionalModules: [
        PropertiesPanelModule,

        // Re-use original bpmn-properties-module, see CustomPropsProvider
        {[InjectionNames.bpmnPropertiesProvider]: ['type', OriginalPropertiesProvider.propertiesProvider[1]]},
        {[InjectionNames.propertiesProvider]: ['type', CustomPropsProvider]},

        // Re-use original palette, see CustomPaletteProvider
        {[InjectionNames.originalPaletteProvider]: ['type', OriginalPaletteProvider]},
        {[InjectionNames.paletteProvider]: ['type', CustomPaletteProvider]},
      ],
      propertiesPanel: {
        parent: '#properties'
      }
      ,
      moddleExtension: {
        custom: customModdle
      }
    });

    this.load();
  }

  handleError(err: any) {
    if (err) {
      console.warn('Ups, error: ', err);
    }
  }

  load(): void {
    const url = '/assets/bpmn/initial.bpmn';
    this.Http.get(url, {
      headers: {observe: 'response'}, responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe(
      (x: any) => {
        console.log('Fetched XML, now importing: ', x);
        this.modeler.importXML(x, this.handleError);
      },
      this.handleError
    );
  }

  save(): void {
    this.modeler.saveXML((err: any, xml: any) => 
     this.form =xml);
    // console.log('Result of saving XML: ', err, xml));
    this.http.savexml(this.form).subscribe((data) => {
console.log(data);
    }
    )}
}
```

i tried post xml created in node but nothing happened!! in fact gave me this error

```
" Error Code: 200
Message: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/"
```

please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to just upload a file on your server. The nodejs logic you implemented shouldn't work because of its async nature and it seems you're trying to put all your data into the body in a non standard way that can include headers and some other unwanted data.

Since you're already using an HTTP request on Express and your goal in the end is just to upload a file, you may want to use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

In this case you're going to pass the xml file on Angular with `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` and by giving a name to the file that Express will recognize:
For instance (taken originally from the official library's github linked above and adapted):

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="xml-name-up-to-you" />
</form>
```

Once you've implemented this part on Angular, you can write something like this on your Express application:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) // folder in which the upload will be saved

var app = express()

app.post('/', upload.single('xml-name-up-to-you'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `xml-name-up-to-you` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: does multer work for save xml data created on angular becuase i dont want upload files from my disk

Comment: from the point of view of the backend every file is the same. While multer uses a folder you can simply upload the file, use it by reading with the filesystem library `fs` and then you can delete it with the aformentioned.